# $("body").on("drop") with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone

I have a dropzone that works great. I also have a few elements as additional "targets" where the user can drop files.

Problem is, I don't know how to "forward" the dropped files from the target element to the dropzone for upload. I'd prefer something such as the following code sample over spawning multiple dropzones, as that feels very hacky in this scenario, given that in the future the number of target-drop elements may be 10 or 15+.

```
"drop": function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    myDropzone.upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer); // Any way to do something like this?

}
```

Comment: can you explain more about your expected output?

Comment: @Justcode I have one `dropzone` that if you drop files onto, they will be uploaded. But I have other "drop areas" that are not initialized `dropzones`, but that users should be able to drop files onto. And I can't find a way to "forward" the captured file by the `drop` event to the `dropzone` element to actually get uploaded.

Comment: Can you load html and sample data? create snippet if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by accessing `Dropzone.instances` and grabbing the instance you want. If you only have one, then grab `Dropzone.instances[0]`. If you have more than one, then you can find the one with the element that has the right `id` on it. Once you have that reference you can call `drop` and forward along the `dataTransfer` object from your custom zone's `drop` event.

The code for your `drop` event handler could look like this:

```
function (e) {
  // make sure to avoid default browser handling (opens file in a new tab/window)
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files.length) {
    // you could pass along the entire event, but probably best to just pass what you need
    Dropzone.instances[0].drop({ dataTransfer: e.dataTransfer });
  }
}
```

[Here's a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9nlrl5qk6) with a working example. It doesn't actually upload files to a server, but you'll see they get added to the dropzone as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.